# Convert xml date output yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss to dd-mmm-yy using xsl1.0

Tags: xml, date, xslt, date-formatting

My XML outputs a due date in the format of yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.

I would like it to show dd-mmm-yy instead, for example 20-Nov-15.

This is what I am working on in my XSL1.0 stylesheet (simplified):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:user-scripts" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras-corp.com">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Action Item No</td>
            <td>Need Date</td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="action_id"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="due_date"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please advise how I can accomplish the new date format dd-mmm-yy in my XSL stylesheet, and exactly where to put in the code (it'd be great if you can paste the whole structure back to me so I can comprehend... total rookie here!)

Thank you!

Comment: There may be built in functions depending on what XSLT processor you're using as well - or you might have the option to include a JavaScript function (for example) depending on your processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, that doesn't require any extensions, is to use [`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) to get the pieces of date that you need and use an element structure to hold the month translations.

Example...

**XML Input** (complete guess since you didn't supply an example)

```
<Item>
    <action_id>A123</action_id>
    <due_date>2015-11-20T10:00:15</due_date>
</Item>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:local="local" exclude-result-prefixes="local">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <local:months>
        <local:month>Jan</local:month>
        <local:month>Feb</local:month>
        <local:month>Mar</local:month>
        <local:month>Apr</local:month>
        <local:month>May</local:month>
        <local:month>Jun</local:month>
        <local:month>Jul</local:month>
        <local:month>Aug</local:month>
        <local:month>Sep</local:month>
        <local:month>Oct</local:month>
        <local:month>Nov</local:month>
        <local:month>Dec</local:month>
    </local:months>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Action Item No</td>
                        <td>Need Date</td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="action_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:variable name="year" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,3,2)"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="monthNbr" 
                                    select="number(substring(due_date,6,2))"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="month"
                                    select="document('')/*/local:months/local:month[position() = $monthNbr]"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="day" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,9,2)"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'-',$month,'-',$year)"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Action Item No</td>
            <td>Need Date</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>A123</td>
            <td>20-Nov-15</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I broke the `substring()`'s out into multiple `xsl:variable`'s to make it easier to see what's going on, but they aren't absolutely necessary.

---

**EDIT**

Here's an alternative that uses `xsl:choose` instead the local element structure...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Action Item No</td>
                        <td>Need Date</td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="action_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:variable name="year" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,3,2)"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="monthNbr" 
                                    select="number(substring(due_date,6,2))"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="month">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=1">Jan</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=2">Feb</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=3">Mar</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=4">Apr</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=5">May</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=6">Jun</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=7">Jul</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=8">Aug</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=9">Sep</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=10">Oct</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=11">Nov</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="$monthNbr=12">Dec</xsl:when>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="day" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,9,2)"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'-',$month,'-',$year)"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's another alternative that just uses another `substring()` (might be better than the first even)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="months" select="'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Action Item No</td>
                        <td>Need Date</td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Item">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="action_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:variable name="year" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,3,2)"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="monthNbr" 
                                    select="number(substring(due_date,6,2))"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="month" 
                                    select="substring($months,($monthNbr*3)-2,3)"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="day" 
                                    select="substring(due_date,9,2)"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'-',$month,'-',$year)"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Also a reminder to me, why 2.0 is the way to go. I'm guessing OP is working a web app, and needs to stay in a browser.  I sure wish browsers were 2.0 capable.  I wince every time I have to write 1.0 code.

Comment: AMAZING! I was stuck on this for 3 days... However, when I run the xml locally on my computer the report works perfectly.. but when I put it on the web application report the month disappears.. Argg!!

Comment: @User1218 - Added 2 more alternatives :-)

Comment: the one with added substring worked!! thank you so much!!

Comment: @User1218 - You're very welcome! Please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. Thanks!